# Spring Boot Project Jar file not reading File placed on classpath

Tags: spring-boot, jar, google-cloud-sql

I am connecting my Spring Boot app with Google Cloud Sql and it got connected by placing **Credential File** in *src/main/resources* but **Issue** comes when I try to run the Jar File - [FileNotFound]

*:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)*

**application.properties-**

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:ArpanShoppingApp-863d536d1f93.json
```

and running jar file gives exception

```
java -jar CloudSQLConnect-1.0.jar
```

**Exception-**

```
2018-06-22 10:46:38.393  INFO 1172 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.s.a.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://google/google_sql?cloudSqlInstance=mindful-highway-207309:asia-south1:shopping-db&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false with driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2018-06-22 10:46:38.401  INFO 1172 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.s.a.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Error reading Cloud SQL credentials file.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ArpanShoppingApp-863d536d1f93.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/arpan/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/CloudSQLConnect/target/CloudSQLConnect-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ArpanShoppingApp-863d536d1f93.json
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:133) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.sql.autoconfig.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.setCredentialsProperty(GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java:167) [spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-1.0.0.M1.jar!/:1.0.0.M1]
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.sql.autoconfig.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.defaultJdbcInfoProvider(GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java:107) [spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-1.0.0.M1.jar!/:1.0.0.M1]
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.sql.autoconfig.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$edf77794.CGLIB$defaultJdbcInfoProvider$1(<generated>) [spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-1.0.0.M1.jar!/:1.0.0.M1]
```

Comment: did you try `classpath*:` ?

Comment: yes-it didn't worked out.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a limitation of spring-cloud-gcp. It seems like credential files must be on the filesystem and cannot be package into a jar. The latest code has [a better error message](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6fd0dfcb5efde595f870f5a9ff697f0317506068/spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java#L256) than the M1 version that you're using.

Comment: It should also be said that limitation only applies to SQL integrations in spring-cloud-gcp. Every other integration supports classpath credentials.