# FileNotFoundException while accessing a file in bootstrap.yml, even the file is present under /resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I created a Spring boot project's fat jar using `mvn package`. Inside the `/resources/bootstrap.yml` I am trying to access a file which is also under `/resources`.

**`location: classpath:secret.json`.**

`bootstrap.yml` and `secret.json` both are inside `/resources` package.

But I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [secret.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/test/Downloads/Demo/demo-api/target/demo-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/secret.json`

The same is working in IDE. What could be the wrong?

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: <something>
      sql:
        instance-connection-name: <something>
        database-name: <something>
      credentials:
        location: classpath:secret.json
      secretmanager:
        enabled: true
        project-id: <something>
        credentials:
          location: classpath:secret.json
```

I can see the `secret.json` under classpath in the decompiled jar.
[image: decompiled jar]

The project structure;
[image: project]

Closing the question. It's an limitation by spring-cloud.
[Spring Boot Project Jar file not reading File placed on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981257/spring-boot-project-jar-file-not-reading-file-placed-on-classpath/50990669#50990669).
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/339

Comment: How did you get the secret.json into `BOOT-INF/classes/ ` ? You should locate your files into `src/main/resources` and that will enable you to access them via classpath..

Comment: @khmarbaise it's added by maven I believe. Shouldn't `/resouces` file come under `BOOT-INF/classes/`?

Comment: Ah sure mistaken that... but it has to be `src/main/resources` furthermore the question is: How to do you try to read that file?

Comment: @khmarbaise edited the question details. `bootstrap.yml` is where I am trying accessing the classpath

Comment: Also if I write `classpath:src/main/resources/secret.json` I get surefile test failed because of same FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Please show the code which tries to load that file...

Comment: It's a Spring's config file and loaded by the Spring itself, I am not loading it anywhere in my code.

Comment: Apparently it has to be a file and a file is in this sense an actual file resource on the file system. A file in a jar or other archive is **not** a file in that sense and can only be loaded through an `InputStream` and not a `java.util.File`. Which is also **exactly** what the exception is telling you `cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:`

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use **file:** instead of classpath:

Try like this

spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/Users/subhachandra/secret.json

Reference : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1733

Comment: I know it works with `file:` but cannot use `file:`

Comment: You can refer this to load credentials

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_credentials